# Connect to replica set within mongo shell

Tags: mongodb, shell, connection-string, replicaset

I'm trying to write a Mongo shell script that connects to two databases, searches for some document(s) in one, and inserts the found document(s) into the other.  Kinda like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
mongo --shell --nodb <<EOF
var db1 = new Mongo( '...' );
var db2 = new Mongo( '...' );
db1.collection.findOne( {...} ).forEach( function( r ) { 
  db2.collection.save( r ) 
});
```

The trick is, both databases are replica sets, and require a username and password.

What is the syntax for using `new Mongo()` to connect to a replica set and authenticating as a particular user?  I tried to use a Mongo URI (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/) but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a replica set to test this on but I think you can use the Mongo() constructor like this

`conn = Mongo("replicasetname/host:port")`

from there I think you'll need to get the database manually with

`db = conn.getDB("myDatabase")`

and then authenticate

`db.auth(user, pass)`

This could all depend on what shell version you're using as well. I don't see any documentation on using the replica set connection in the latest version so I don't know if it's deprecated or just not mentioned anymore. Hope this helps.

Comment: Cool glad it worked. You might also want to try. `Mongo("host:port/?replicaSet=name")` that seems to be the documented way now to connect to replicas.